# Issues connecting to Cassandra remotely

Tags: cassandra, debian, cql

I have in a VPS `Cassandra 3.0.8` in Debian. If I connect through ssh and execute cqlsh it works but I'm trying to connect remotely with DevCenter and I can't because if I edit the `cassandra.yaml` file and in `rpc_address` line I set `rpc_address: 0.0.0.0` or my public IP the server doesn't listen the ports 0.0.0.0 or IP public. I try too change `listen_address:localhost` for `listen_address:0.0.0.0` and I change `start_rpc: false` to `true` but nothing.

What I have to do to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you probably have a firewall that's blocking connections.

Regarding the settings for rpc_address, listen_address, etc, here's a typical setup:

```
#Accept connections from any interface
rpc_address: 0.0.0.0
#The address to tell other nodes & drivers to connect to.
broadcast_rpc_address: <public_ip>
#Address for inter-node connections *never* 0.0.0.0
listen_address: <private_ip>
```